# Superposition to find voltage U2

Tags: operational-amplifier

This is my op-amp

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGiBrR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I used superposition to find U1, where I got  $$U_{A1}=\ -U1$$

2nd part of solving the circruit when U2 is active
$$R_2+R_4=\ 2R\ \ \ \ \ \ and\ \ R_3//R_5=\ \frac{R}{2}\ \ \ \    $$

$$U_{A2}=(1+\frac{R_6}{R_1})*(\frac{\frac{R}{2}}{\frac{R}{2}+2R})U_2=\frac{2}{5}U_2  $$

There is not way I can prove if this is right or wrong so I would really appreciate some help.

Which load resistance is connected to U3 ?

Comment: R3 is not || to R5. The load resistance seen by U3 is R3 + R2||(R4+R5) = 16.67 kohm.

Comment: @Andy aka  what is U2 then ?

Comment: U2 is U2 i.e. whatever you want it to be. If you mean what load does U2 see then it's the same as U3 (given the values you have chosen in your circuit).

Comment: @Andy aka, thank you. I am not sure if the way I have found U2 is correct

Comment: U2 is an input voltage and you are confusing me. U2 is an input. If you mean something else then use the correct terminology. While you are thinking about this I see you have asked 10 questions recently and haven't formally accepted any answers. Is this because all the answers are poor?

Comment: @Andy aka sorry my mistake. I meant UA2 as seen on the equation above - I dont know if that one is correct

Comment: @Andy aka, the ones that had good answers I mrked them as answered . If you could help me with if my Ua2 is right

Comment: @be1995 Sorry, got a constant wrong. I get \$U_\text{a}=-U_1+\frac25\cdot\left(U_2+U_3\right)\$.

Answer (score 2):

Voltage \$U_{A2} = (1+\dfrac{R_6}{R_1})\cdot U_{R_5}\$

And, \$U_{R_5}\$ (when U3 is shorted) is \$\dfrac{R_5}{R_4+R_5}\cdot U_{R_3}\$

And, \$U_{R_3}\$ (U3 is shorted) is \$\dfrac{R_3||(R_4 +R_5)}{R_3||(R_4 +R_5)+R_2}\cdot U_2  \$

Does this allow you to check your answer or is there still a discrepancy?

Comment: if I am putting the values for the resistors as a final result I am getting $$U_{A2}=\frac{2}{5}U_2  $$. Is that correct ?

Comment: Isn't that what you stated in your question?

Comment: I asked if the way I have solved that part of the question is right  because I am not sure

Comment: Do you get the same answer if you plugged the resistor values into my equations?

Comment: when I plugged 10k for every resistor in the on your answer. I get the same result as mine

Comment: Well that's good news. I didn't look at your derivation; I did my own and if the answers are the same then there's a good probability that both are correct. I used my derivation because R3 is not in parallel with R5 (as you assert in your question and as I mentioned 2 hours ago in a comment).

Comment: just confused because I have been told before that is it not right and just cannot figure it out why this result might be wrong

Comment: Well maybe the person telling you is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEHRbe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
0=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_7\\
\\
0=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_6
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_voltage_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{z}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_7}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
0=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
0=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{z}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{z}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, when we have an ideal opamp we know that \$\text{V}_\alpha:=\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_3=\text{V}_4\$. So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
0=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
0=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_5}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{z}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_5}=\frac{\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{z}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, when \$\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2=\text{R}_3=\text{R}_4=\text{R}_5=\text{R}_6=\text{R}_7\$, for the output voltage we get:

$$\text{V}_5=\frac{2\text{V}_\text{y}+4\text{V}_\text{z}-7\text{V}_\text{x}}{9}\tag{5}$$